# How to ask user String input until user is done?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the names of each song in the DJ's playlist: ");
        System.out.println("When finished, enter done.");
        ArrayList <String> NamesOfSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop)
        {
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("done"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                NamesOfSongs.add(scan.nextLine());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(NamesOfSongs);
        }
```

Input strings need to be added to the ArrayList until user enters "done" and the method is finished.

Results in:  (after I enter 3 strings and done TWICE)

```
Enter the names of each song in the DJ's playlist:
When finished, enter done.
jjjj
kkkkk
iiii
done
done
[kkkkk, done]
```

Comment: I don't need to compare strings. I need to add name of songs into an ArrayList that are input by user until he/she is done entering. I don't know how to format my while loop such way.

Comment: Yes you do, otherwise you wouldn't have done this: `if (input!="done")`, which is wrong and is the reason I gave you that link.

Comment: @KristinaMortimer You seem to have everything correct except for how you compare the input with the `"done"`-string. You need to use the `equals` method.

Comment: Use `if(!input.equals("done")) { }` to compare String, because `!=` not matches

Comment: Also, the way you edited your question doesn't even compile (`String` has no `next()` method)

Comment: Please advise on the incorrect result that I got.

Comment: You use `NamesOfSongs.add(scan.nextLine());` in the else => so you enter a new value => use `NamesOfSongs.add(input)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare String, you have to use `equals` method. 
For exemple `input.equals("done")`. This method returns `true` if the String"s" are equals.

In the else code, you must not use `NamesOfSongs.add(scan.nextLine());` because you ask the user to enter a new value. You want to retrieve the value already entered
So, use `NamesOfSongs.add(input);`

And, to display the contents of the ArraysList you can use a loop 'for'

```
    /* Print the song*/
    for(int i = 0; i < NamesOfSongs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(NamesOfSongs.get(i));
    }
```

---

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the names of each song in the DJ's playlist: ");
    System.out.println("When finished, enter done.");
    ArrayList <String> NamesOfSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean loop = true;

    while(loop) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        if(input.equals("done")) {
            /* Stop the input => stop while loop*/
            loop = false; 
        } else {
            /* add song */
            NamesOfSongs.add(input);
        }
    }

    /* Print the song*/
    for(int i = 0; i < NamesOfSongs.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(NamesOfSongs.get(i));
    }
}
```